# Ethers.js provider error: non-configurable property '"provider"'

Tags: metamask, ethers.js

I'm using Metamask detect ethereum provider, and while the app is starting, I'm trying to create ethers signer and provider objects and store them in Vue Pinia store. However, when I use the stored signer, I encounter the error:

> TypeError: proxy must report the same value for the non-writable,
> non-configurable property '"provider"'

```
 const provider = await detectEthereumProvider();
 if (provider) {
   useEthersStore().setProviderSigner()
   startApp(provider)
 }
```

```
async setProviderAndSigner() {
     if (window.ethereum) {
         this.provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
         this.signer = this.provider.getSigner();
     } 
}
```

I'm also wondering what the best approach is to handle ethers provider and signer, without having to define them every time they are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error come from the `Vue` reactivity system it can cause issues with certain libraries or objects, like the `ethers.js` `provider` and `signer`

To fix that, first be sure sure you are using the latest `ethers.js` and `Pinia` then instead of storing the provider and signer directly in the `Pinia` you should store them in non-reactive way using `markRaw` like that:

```
import { markRaw } from 'vue';

async setProviderAndSigner() {
  if (window.ethereum) {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();

    this.provider = markRaw(provider);
    this.signer = markRaw(signer);
  }
}
```